# Parse: How to save single column of PFObject

Tags: swift, parse-platform, real-time, latency

I have an issue where if a user posts something on my app, and a user with bad internet connection tries to view it, the post is deleted. I think this is because in my code, the client saves the array of posts every 5 seconds or so. Since the client with bad internet connection has an old version of the posts, when they try to view the post, the old version is saved and therefore the new post is deleted. In order to fix this, I need to save columns in an object individually and not affect the new posts column. How do I do this?

Comment: You fix it by not arbitrarily overwriting your data model every 5 seconds. Only save the new post at the time the user makes it.

Comment: @AaronBrager I need to do it every 5 seconds because I need to check if it is expired and if it is, expire it.

Comment: You should use push notifications, not polling, to *tell* your app if something changes. But even if you're going to "check" something every 5 seconds, that's different from "overwriting" every 5 seconds.

Comment: @AaronBrager sorry, I have another value called "viewers" that holds an array of the people who have viewed the post and it changes when people click on it. I need to update the whole object in order to update this one value so what should I do if the post on the client's device is old and it is also saving the old version of the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the value in **updatedAt**, if the local value updatedAt is lower than the one on server, you just wont update it... I think you can do that in cloud code with **beforeSave** trigger